# Divide numbers into decimals from UILabels - xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, uilabel, ibaction

I have two `UILabels` that shows numbers. They are updated through `UISteppers`. I would like to include a third `UILabel` that calculates the division between `UILabel1` and `UILabel2` when the user presses on either of the `UISteppers`. (The two `UILabels` are therefore .text)

I know the method should be done if both the `IBAction` of the two `UISteppers` but I am having trouble thinking how the method should be written.

Does somebody have any idea how to write the method?

Thanks.

**to update UILabel1**

```
- (IBAction)smashChanged:(id)sender {

self.smashLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                         [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];
}
```

Comment: I update Label1 and Label 2 by UIStepper. Therefore the codes are really similar. Please see above... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method `floatValue` (or `intValue`) of `NSString`:

```
float value1 = [self.label1.text floatValue];
float value2 = [self.label2.text floatValue];
float value = (value2 == 0.0) ? 0 : value1 / value2; // This gives 0 if value2 is equal to 0
self.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value]; // 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked like a charm. At the moment, when it is say 1/0 label3 shows 'inf'. Is there a way to show 0, instead of inf? Also, can it show to 2 decimal places instead? Thanks.

Comment: That has worked beautifully. Last question, is there a way where I can put a '%' sign after the value? So user's know straightaway it is a percentage. Or just put a label next to value with % on it? Thanks.

Comment: You can change the string in `stringWithFormat` as you like, for example: `self.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%", value];`. `%.2f` will be used to format the number, the last `%` will be displayed in the label.

Comment: Hey, I just did self.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%", value]; as you have just said but the '%' sign did not come up when I am running the program - do you know why?